# Get size of workspacedirectories from Jenkinsnodes via Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson, jenkins-groovy

I want to print out the size of the directories from my Jenkinsnodes

My Script:

```
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import Jenkins.*

jenkins = Jenkins.instance

for (slave in jenkins.nodes) {
  wsRoot = slave.getWorkspaceRoot()
  println( "Nodename:      " + slave.getNodeName() )

  for (dir in wsRoot.list()) {

    println("---------------------------------------------------------")
    println("   dirname:  " + dir )
    println("   dirspace:  " + dir.length()   )

  }

}
```

But with this Script I get as size "0"(if dir is empty) or "4096" for a dir which is 28mb.

I try the same with File

```
  for (dir in wsRoot.list()) {
    println("-------------------------------------------------------")
    println("   dirname:      " + dir )
    File DirFiles = new File(dir.toString())
    def sampleDirSize = DirFiles.directorySize()
    println("   DirSpace:     " + sampleDirSize   ) 
  }
```

But here i get the Error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/C:\Jenkins-Slave\jars\workspace\Testprojekt
```

Because the master is a Linuxserver and some nodes a Windowsservers which create a wrong Filelocation.

Is there a solution to show the dir size correct in mb for all nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import Jenkins.*

nByte = 0
nByteDir = 0

jenkins = Jenkins.instance

for (slave in jenkins.nodes) {
  wsRoot = slave.getWorkspaceRoot()
  println( "Nodename: " + slave.getNodeName() )

  for (dir in wsRoot.list()) {
    nByteDir = 0
    println("=====================================================================")
    println("   dirname:   " + dir )

    showFiles( dir )

    println("   Byte Dir:  " + nByteDir )
  }

  println("=====================================================================")
  println("Byte Total: " + nByte )
  println("#####################################################################")
}


def showFiles( dir ) {
    for ( files in dir.list() ){
        if( files.isDirectory()   ) {
            showFiles( files );
        } else {
            ByteCounter( files.length() )
        }
    }
}

def ByteCounter ( c )
{
  nByte = nByte + c
  nByteDir = nByteDir + c
}
```